# Unable to trade or battle pokemon, how to fix?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

I bought both Ruby and Sapphire for my girlfriend and myself to play.

After getting some medals and catching some Pokemon we decided to trade and battle a bit with Pokemon level 20 and having only 3 medals.

We appeared in the PSS as friends online and we can issue battle or trades, but after accepting a message displays and the attempt is canceled. The message we get is:

> Combat/trade canceled any of the participants is missing

- We tried to trade and battle people online and we don't have any problems.
- We used local trading/combat. Tried internet too
- The Pokemon where caught and raised in-game, no hacks nor strange trades with other games.
- I have a 3ds XL and she has a new 3ds XL
- Both games are updated with the latest patch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When Wifi battling, the PSS will give you an option to enable voice chat.

If you are the **host**, i.e. the one sending the challenge, you can either choose 'Yes' or 'No' to enable or disable voice-chat. It doesn't really matter which.

If you are the **joining** player, you will either get a message saying something like:

> Enable Voice Chat? Yes/No

OR

> Disable Voice Chat? Yes/No

In either case, the joining player **must choose 'Yes' in order to accept & join the battle** - choosing 'No' will count as a declined battle offer.

**Source:** battling every day*

---

<sub>*...[to claim my rightful plaaaaace!!!](https://youtu.be/8ZdzY9TGu1c?t=74)</sub>

Comment: really i didn't had those problems in X & Y, now i'm curious how they ended with this decisión it's completely ilogical from my point of view

Comment: @xerido - this is just one instance of terrible UI design that make up 6th Gen Pokemon. The GTS is a mess, Wonder trade exits after every trade, The VS. Recorder etc - so many poorly layed out menus